# I can't put my device to sleep(Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: suspend, hibernate

The only thing I have is a [dmesg](https://gist.github.com/pavlaras/b7073c7a1839e2bc6fddbbcd9526f9b3).
Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: if you need more information please feel free to comment me and ask me to add more. Maybe a kernel header or something, or a log or execute a command in terminal

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details about your problem.

Comment: how ?? i don't know how to debug this to add more details, i only know how to get a dmesg to show the error.
I simply can't put the device to sleep. Even if i manually put it to sleep, it will wake up again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dual booting maybe look at this

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2334278

Comment: yes im actually dual booting. I will check asap the link Sam thank you. 
Did you see the dmesg ? See lines https://gist.github.com/pavlaras/b7073c7a1839e2bc6fddbbcd9526f9b3#file-dmesg-txt-L952-L997
when it goes offline, it suddenly starts booting up again on its own, without printing the reason.

Comment: This is a link only answer. Consider adding essential info to it, and keep the link as reference.

Answer (score 0):

well, i found the problem. 
how i found it:
First i used the ubuntu live installation disk, that i created, to boot to ubuntu 18.04 in order to check if it was me that i did something wrong after flashing ubuntu and i realised that i can't hibernate my PC there too.

I opened terminal and i did: `uname -r` to see what's my kernel version. It was 4.15.

I then used a ubuntu 16.04 live installation disk and did the same. I realised that in ubuntu 14.04 i can hibernate normally. So i checked my kernel version again and it was 4.14.21

After that i googled to check if a downgrade is possible and if i could use ubuntu 18.04 with a kernel version 4.14.21 without breaking it.

The answers i found differ from each other , so i just took the risk and yes it worked ! Now i can hibernate again.

I can't post here how to downgrade the kernel version , because that's answered elsewhere. Keep in mind that if anyone else has the same issue like me, you can downgrade but before you delete the other kernel images do a restart to make sure that you can boot. If you don't boot then just choose advanced option in grub menu and boot with your older kernel (the one you used before) and remove the one you installed.

Comment: well.... normally we should debug this, but at least me i had no idea of how to debug this , because it showed no actual error. 
Keep in mind that downgrade is not always the best option and we don't help the community fix bugs. Downgrade only as a final option when you have already tried to debug it just like i did.